# Solr - How to search in all fields without passing query field?

Tags: php, solr, lucene

I have tried as below,

```
<field name="collector" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false"  multiValued="true" />
```

and copy all my fields to **copyField** as below,

```
<copyField source="fullname" dest="collector"/>
<copyField source="email" dest="collector"/>
<copyField source="city" dest="collector"/>
```

and also I have put all **copyField** tags below

```
<fields>

</fields>
```

tags. But I cant search in all fields. I have to pass **fullname** before query like,

```
q=fullname:Mayur
```

I want search by,

```
q=Mayur
```

And I should search all fields contains **Mayur** word.

Help me please

Comment: If you search for `q=collector:Mayur`, do you get the correct results? This will help determine whether the problem is the "collector" field itself, or just configuring "collector" as a default search field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the fields have stored=true

```
<field name="field_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

True if the value of the field should be retrievable during a search.

Use the Default Search Field : 
The  is used by Solr when parsing queries to identify which field name should be
searched in queries where an explicit field name has not been used.

```
<defaultSearchField>collector</defaultSearchField>
```

in your schema.xml

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Its working by changing "stored=true".

Answer (score 1):

This has been deprecated in solr 7:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/major-changes-in-solr-7.html
It's recommended to use `df` parameter.