# Can not search in the field which I defined in schema.xml like copyField

Tags: search, solr, solr-schema

I've added to the schema.xml the multivalued field in the following way:

```
<field name="text_qs" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

And added two fields to it:

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text_qs"/>
<copyField source="symbol" dest="text_qs"/>
```

After that I perform indexing of the solr, restart it, but still I can not search in this field `text_qs`.
I checked it by search `text_qs:ge` in the solr admin http://localhost:8061/solr/admin/.

### Could you please ask somebody why?

In general, I tried to create search in the certain fields. Because now we can search in the field text_def, which is `<defaultSearchField>text_def</defaultSearchField>`.
And this field text_def was defined in the similar way like:

```
<field name="text_def" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

It just has nor copyFields:

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text_def"/>
<copyField source="symbol" dest="text_def"/>
<copyField source="numb" dest="text_def"/>
....
```

So now when we type `'ge'` we search this `'ge'` in the default search field text_def, and we search in fields `'name', 'symbol', 'numb',....`
But we want search only in `'name'` and `'symbol'`. And that's why I try to create the field `text_qs`.

### Does this correct?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002255/solr-how-to-search-in-all-fields-without-passing-query-field/30010009#30010009

Comment: No, unfortunately, `stored="true"` didn't help me. As for this link: my issue exactly vice versa. No I can search like `q=ge` but it search in the default_search field. And I want to create my multivalued field `text_qs` and search in this field `q=text_qs:ge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with change stored=true

```
<field name="text_qs" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

True if the value of the field should be retrievable during a search.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for confusing.
As it turned out, the issue was in the indexing. The script which perform indexing don't useful for this situation, I had to use another script.
Thanks for help!